# Android Development-Adding Icon into Actionbar

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am now following this tutorial in Official Android site:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html

I am stuck at Action Bar. I followed the way tutorial indicated adding a  tag in main.xml like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" /> 
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="never" /> 
</menu>
```

and changing onCreateOptionsMenu() as following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

ps:I don't know why I cannot use "main_activity_actions", it is like a undefined variable in R

Then I run my project on Nexus 7, However the button(@string/action_search) is always in overflow under three-dot button.

I am really confused

Answer (score 1):

> the button(@string/action_search) is always in overflow under three-dot button.

That is because you have set `android:showAsAction="never"`.

As per the [Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html), this means that menu item will never be placed in the action bar. To show it in the action bar, you usually want to set `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried "ifRoom", however search button is still under overflow list.

Comment: Are you using the support library Action Bar?